# R json multiple columns

Tags: r, jsonlite

I have a json that looks like this right now:

```
[{"id":"123","symbol":"A","price":[5,3,1,2],"Value":[23,2,4,30]}, {"id":"334","symbol":"B","price":[6,2,2,2],"Value":[2,21,42,3]}]
```

How can i turn it into a data frame with two rows that has columns like these:

```
id | symbol | price1 | price2 | price3 | price4 | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4

I have tried using fromJSON(jsondata)
```

but it throws me back a list, and after binding the list, I am getting for example one column of price with each different price returning as a different row instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `fromJSON` from `jsonlite` to convert to a `data.frame` and then `unnest` the `list` elements into 'long' format.  It may be better to keep it in the 'long' format

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
fromJSON(str1) %>% 
   unnest(c(price, Value)) %>%
   group_by(id, symbol) %>%
   mutate(ind = row_number()) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = ind, values_from = c(price, Value))
# A tibble: 2 x 10
#  id    symbol price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4 Value_1 Value_2 Value_3 Value_4
#  <chr> <chr>    <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
#1 123   A            5       3       1       2      23       2       4      30
#2 334   B            6       2       2       2       2      21      42       3
```

NOTE: `pivot_wider` is from the `devel` version of `tidyr` (`‘0.8.3.9000’`)

---

Or another option would be `dcast` from `data.table`

```
df1 <- fromJSON(str1) %>% 
    unnest(c(price, Value))

library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), id + symbol  ~rowid(id, symbol), value.var = c('price', 'Value'))
#    id symbol price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4 Value_1 Value_2 Value_3 Value_4
#1: 123      A       5       3       1       2      23       2       4      30
#2: 334      B       6       2       2       2       2      21      42       3
```

#### data

```
str1 <- '[{"id":"123","symbol":"A","price":[5,3,1,2],"Value":[23,2,4,30]}, {"id":"334","symbol":"B","price":[6,2,2,2],"Value":[2,21,42,3]}]'
```

Comment: i seem to keep getting this Error: Column `c(price, Value)` must be length 2 (the number of rows) or one, not 4

Comment: i tried with only your code, still getting the above error

Comment: thanks anyway, i will try and investigate to see where is the issue

Comment: i changed the unnest line to unnest(price, Value) and it works. but now the other error i am getting is pivot_wide cannot be found. tried tidyr::pivot_wide

Comment: @user7729135. It is a new function in the dev version of [tidyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr). If you insstall from github, should work

Comment: i see. how do i install that version of tidyr?

Comment: i can't seem to get the developer tidyr installed. will try to use the current version

Comment: will update again. still trying the first method. interesting that they are replacing spread and gather from tidyr too